# Is anyone at Hogwarts married?

Tags: harry-potter

Is anybody at Hogwarts married? Professors, groundskeepers, lunch ladies? (Joking about the lunch ladies.)

For however well we got to know the faculty of Hogwarts, I don't remember spouses or children being mentioned once.

I've never been to a school of witchcraft and wizardry, but in the schools I have been to, married professors are by far the norm, and it often comes up one way or another (especially if you know them for 7 or so years).

In contrast, Hogwarts faculty seem to have a Jedi Order vibe going on.

Does Hogwarts have any restrictions on marriage, or it is just coincidental?

Comment: Related, not quite dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59970/3567

Comment: @SachinShekhar whuh?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. From [Red Nose Day Chat, BBC Online, March 12, 2001](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bbc-rednose.htm)

   > Have any of the Hogwarts professors had spouses?
   >   **JKR**: Good question - **yes, a few of them**, but that information is sort of restricted - you'll find out why...
2. Book canon never elaborates on any spouses (see the last bullet point for my guesses on "why").
3. Pottermore [has at least one example](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Professor_McGonagall#Marriage) of a married professor:

   **Professor McGonagall was married** (to her former boss at the MoM, Elphinstone Urquart) while already a Professor at Hogwarts. But she is widowed by the time of the events of the books.
4. There can be married professors in the future as well - Neville Longbottom was a Profesor as per *DH*; and married Hannah Abbott as per [Carnegie Hall interview](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more/). I can try and find out if the dates match up.
5. Salazar Slytherin and Rowena Ravenclaw had kids. Not proof of having been married (nor that they were married during teaching at Hogwarts post-founding), yet, the times being what they were - medieval England - that is likely.
6. Phineas Nigellus Black was a Headmaster at Hogwarts; and therefore *likely* a Professor (no definite proof of that, however). He also was married to Ursula Flint according to Black Family Tree tapestry and had kids. But here's no definite proof that he was married *while* being at Hogwarts.
7. As far as other professors, some we simply don't know, some are definite "NO":

   - Dumbledore, as we found out, [is homosexual](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41282/did-j-k-rowing-always-consider-dumbledore-gay) and, presumably, never married (not sure if gay marriage is forbidden in Wizarding world outside of slashfics, but given that it seems to be socially based on middle-ages Britain, probably not).
   - [Hagrid never got married](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/did-jkr-ever-allude-to-what-happened-to-relationship-between-hagrid-and-madame-m)
   - Professor Binns was a ghost.
   - According to Pottermore, Quirrel wasn't married.
8. As far as "coincidental", I don't think so.

   There are a couple of reasons why we don't know about Professors' spouses?

   - The books are written from the point of view of young kids. They generally wouldn't know or care if the boring old people teaching them are married, and with the exception of Hagrid and the Trio, aren't very buddy-buddy or close to the kids.

     Good storytelling only adds information that is important to establish setting, develop a character, or progress the plot. Teachers' spouses likely wouldn't do either of the 3, and the books are already pretty big and long as they are.
   - Hogwarts was clearly and largely modeled on British boarding schools. I have heard many references that much of the staff at such schools wasn't married due to them frequently NOT being co-ed, and those that were married, the spouses didn't live on campus.

Comment: Hm...so that was 2001. Thirteen years later have we found out why?

Comment: @PaulDraper - [I asked that earlier on SFF](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/why-exactly-was-information-on-hogwarts-professors-spouses-restricted). No credible information was found so far.

Comment: Side note: least [people think I stole the quote for #1 from James Patterson's answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5019/i-dont-understand-why-there-is-such-a-huge-vote-discrepancy-between-these-two-a): mine was posted 2 minutes earlier than his.

Comment: I'd suggest that Madam Pomfrey was very likely married, given the form of address.

Comment: @StanRogers - worth an answer on its own

Comment: `Salazar Slytherin and Rowena Ravenclaw had kids.` how about rephrase a little?

Comment: @Cthulhu - and **that**, boys and girls, is how bad fanfics get born.

Comment: "Dumbledore, as we found out, is homosexual" _that_ was news. Any sources?

Comment: @Krumia: This is a question-and-answer site; if you have a question, post it as a question and people will answer it.

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/7053982.stm

Comment: @SebastianHöffner - you should bias towards on-site resources :))) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41282/did-j-k-rowing-always-consider-dumbledore-gay

Comment: @EricLippert: This is a _one of a kind_ question and answer site. It is appreciated if you provide sources when you say something. If you say something _really_ surprising, doubly so. :)

Comment: It's been printed in some official HP books that [Flitwick and Sprout were in a long term relationship](https://www.therowlinglibrary.com/2017/11/29/hogwarts-houses-editions-quoted-a-fake-rowling-tweet/), so you might want to add that to your answer.

Comment: Dumbledore was born in 1881.  *Lots* of gay men of his generation in England married women (quite probably the majority).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, they apparently have (or have had) spouses.   Presumably the spouses live in Hogsmeade?

[From Red Nose Day Chat, BBC Online, March 12, 2001](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bbc-rednose.htm)

> Have any of the Hogwarts professors had spouses? JKR: Good question -
>   yes, a few of them, but that information is sort of restricted -
>   you'll find out why..

Comment: LOL beat you by 2 minutes :) Good find!